# SQL Server Invalid Column Name and String Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following code snippet from a SQL Server Stored Procedure.

```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(Max)

    SET @sql = N'

    WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT * FROM #TEMP WHERE ...
    ),

    Track AS
    (
      SELECT *,
              CASE WHEN 1B1 = "Track" AND (QTRK_1B1 = "2D QT" OR QTRK_1B1 = "3D QT") THEN "Yes" ELSE "No" END AS Tracking
      FROM CTE
    ),
    ... '

Exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@AirTarget nvarchar(25), @GroundTracker nvarchar(25)', @AirTarget, @GroundTracker
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. When I execute the stored procedure, I am getting errors like:

> Invalid Column Name 'Track'
>
> Invalid Column Name '2D QT'
>
> Invalid Column Name '3D QT'
>
> Invalid Column Name 'Yes'
>
> Invalid Column Name 'No'

But those are not column names from the table. I have Googled and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have tried surrounding those values with single quotes, and I have tried removing the quotes from around those values and nothing works. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL use single quote `'` for string

```
CASE 
    WHEN 1B1 = ''Track'' AND (QTRK_1B1 = ''2D QT'' OR QTRK_1B1 = ''3D QT'') THEN ''Yes'' 
    ELSE ''No'' 
END AS Tracking
```

Answer (score 1):

They all definitely should be single quotes - all places where you have double-quotes. If 
you do that it should at least give you a different message.

You'll also need to wrap `1B1` in square brackets like `[1B1]` as it won't like a column name starting with a number in a `CASE` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help.